# Can I customize the way folders are displayed in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm running Outlook 2007, and I would like to customize the folder view so it sorts by special folders, and then non special folders (like Apple Mail) to make it easier to read.

For example, it currently looks something like this:

- [Actioned]
- [Clients]
- Deleted Items
- Drafts
- Inbox
- Junk Mail
- [People]
- [Personal]
- Sent Items

*Folders in [ ] are normal non special folders.*

I'd like to have it show like this:

- Deleted Items
- Drafts
- Inbox
- Junk
- Sent Items

---

- [Actioned]
- [Clients]
- [People]
- [Personal]

I'm aware that Outlook 2010 displays the folders in a much more human fashion, however I am not able to upgrade at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Favorites view? It can be arranged any way you want. Add the folders you want to the Favorites view, arrange them as you like, and leave the folder view visible so you can get to those less commonly-used folders. Works for me, anyway.

Comment: True, but I use all of my folders frequently, that's why I have them set up in the fashion I do :) I'm also not a fan of the doubling up for information - why should I show a folder twice. Thanks for the answer though.